# How to fix HOG to detect all the persons in a scene?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to detect person in a scene using HOG descriptor and SVM but the program doesn't detect all the present persons in the scene:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>




using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


vector <Rect> drawBoundingBox (vector<vector<Point> > contours)
{
    vector <Rect> listOfRectangles; 
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        // Get bounding box for contour
        Rect roi = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        if (roi.area() > 1000)
        {
            listOfRectangles.push_back(roi);
        }
    }
    //merge rectangles
    int size = listOfRectangles.size();
    for( int k = 0; k < size; k++ )
    {
        listOfRectangles.push_back(Rect(listOfRectangles[k]));
    }
    groupRectangles(listOfRectangles, 1, 0.7);
    return listOfRectangles; 
}


//! main program 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Mat frame_capture,frame_capture2;  
    VideoCapture capture("Baseline/PETS2006/input/in%06d.jpg");   // path to input images
    VideoCapture capture2("Baseline/PETS2006/groundtruth/gt%06d.png"); // path to groundtruth images



    if((!capture.isOpened())&(!capture2.isOpened() )) 
    {
        printf("Could not open video file!!!");
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    Mat gray;

    //! do detection and tracking
    int i=0;


    //Hog Descriptor
    cv::HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.setSVMDetector(cv::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    while (1)
    {   ++i;
        capture >> frame_capture;
        capture2 >> frame_capture2;
        if(i >= 300){

        cv::cvtColor(frame_capture2,gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);


        cv::Mat im_gray;
        cv::equalizeHist( gray, im_gray );
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        findContours(gray,contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
        vector <Rect> listOfRectangles;
        listOfRectangles = drawBoundingBox(contours);


         // HOG person detector
            vector <Rect>  detected_person;


         //Hog detectMultiscale
           hog.detectMultiScale(im_gray, detected_person, 0.0, cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(0,0), 1.05, 4); 



    if(!frame_capture.empty()){
        for (int i =0; i<detected_person.size();++i)
        {
            //rectangle (frame_capture, listOfRectangles[i], Scalar(255,255,0),1,8,0); //! display detections


            //detected persons
            rectangle(frame_capture, detected_person[i], Scalar(255,255,0),2,8,0);
            //putText(frame_capture,"person", detected_person[i].tl(),FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,0.8,cvScalar(200,200,250),1,CV_AA);

        }


    //oVideoWriter.write(frame_capture);
        imshow("video",frame_capture);
        waitKey(25);
    }    
    }
    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;

}
```

I got such a result this image [image: detecte person].What can I do to detect all the persons present in the scene using this approach?Can anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: add more light in the background.

Comment: if the persons in the back are too small (minimum detector size is person height is about 110 pixel) you could try to resize image (increase image size)

Comment: I'm using 720*576 image.

Comment: put the person does not fill the whole image size. Minimum pixel height of the PERSON (not the image) should be about 110 pixel (I didnt measure it in your image)

Comment: So I have to get a height of person greater than 110?

Comment: @Micka: should I resize the persons in all the images??

Comment: extract the areaa where person cqn occur and guess how small those people migh be in that area (coming from perspective foreshortening). Resize the whole image with a factor so that those smallst assumed persons get a size of 110

Comment: I tried to resize the image it is now 900*720 but I got the same result,If I understand what you told me I have to resize the persons to have a height of 110 but I didn't find how to do that

Comment: neednt be exactly 110, can be bigger, too. If you resize the whole image by a factor of 1.5 you'll detect a second person, too (the top-right one). I didnt manage to detect the third one, as I said you should add more light to the scene (probably not possible, but you shouldn't assume perfect results anyways). Welcome to the world of video detection.

Comment: I rescale it using a factor=1.5 it detect 2 persons now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOG is applied not once to whole image, but to windows extracted from image. Those windows are by default 64x128 with overlap of 8 pixels. This method of detection relies on assumption, that human must roughly fill the whole detection window and fit in it. When you want to detect people whose sizes are different from ~64x128, you should create set of scaled images, so there's a higher chance of fitting human into one of the windows.

However, in your code, you use `getDefaultPeopleDetector()` for classification and `detectMultiScale()`, which basically does scaling for you. There might be some other problems - notice that those 2 people fuses a little with the background, so their edges can be miscalculated by HOG and the classifier can take them as a non-person object. Occlusion might be another issue.

You should test your code with other images and check if problem always occurs. Try using different parameters of `detectMultiScale()` - `scaleFactor`, which describes step of scaling and `minNeighbors` describing how many neighboring windows classified by SVM as containing person are needed to label object as a person in the end. Using RGB instead of grayscale should also improve classification. Eventually, you can also try to train your own SVM.

However, remember that is impossible to get 100% accuracy of detector (so far, at least). It's a good idea to have a look at the [Dalal and Triggs article](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) about HOG for pedestrian detection to understand what's going on under the hood of OpenCV implementation (it's partially based on that article).

Comment: afaik detectMultiscale does only downscale the image (or upscale the detection window). That's why the persons must have some minimum size to be detectable.

Comment: I think that depending on whether scaleFactor is >1 or <1 it should be able to either downscale or upscale the image, but I haven't tested it. Manually resizing images (up and down) and calling detect() on each of them should also do.

Comment: @BartekM: How to resize the detected objects in an image??

Comment: You resize whole image and get set of images in different scales (called pyramid). Resizing is done with opencv resize(). Don't forget that downscaled image cannot be smaller than detection window.

Comment: I could get your question wrong. Did you rather mean: how to calculate position of detected object (detected in resized image) in original image from position in resized image?

Comment: I meant how to resize the detected persons,I resized the image (900*720) and I rescale it scale=1.5 and I detect now 2 persons.

Comment: If person at scaled image is at Rect(x, y, w, h) and size of image was multiplied by factor f=1.5, than coming back to original resolution=900*720, person will be located at Rect(x/f, y/f, w/f, h/f)